# Possible to connect Android phone to a port on router

Tags: usb-connection-mode

My son wants to connect his Android phone to a port on his router. The details of phone and environment follow.  Any advice on whether this is possible would be much appreciated.

Phone: WIKO
Model: U FEEL

Android version 6.0 (08)

Developer Optoins: ON

USB Debugging: ON

Verify apps over USB: ON

Select USB Configuration:

(possible options)
- Charging
- MTP
- PTP
- RNDIS
- Audio Source
- MIDI

Disable USB audio routing: ON

Show all ANRs: ON

Comment: With "port" you mean an RJ45 Ethernet port, right? For doing so you need an USB Ethernet adapter and an USB OTG cable. Of course this requires that the device supports USB-OTG and USB-Ethernet adapters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which USB-C to RJ45 adapter for SONY Xperia XZ](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/213821/which-usb-c-to-rj45-adapter-for-sony-xperia-xz) Just the device is different, which does not make a difference - it works for an device or not.

Comment: [How to make Ethernet work on Android over OTG?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/225741/218526)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I violated the forum's strict posting rules....
I found answers to both my questions on a couple of other forums - so, sharing KNOWLEDGE
 1. both my son's WIKO and my SONY XPERIA XZ have reportedly had the driver removed or incapacitated in the Linux kernel and as neither phone is ROOTed there's no way strightforward way to install a driver
 2. and yes Robert, I meant the RJ45 Ethernet port